# Relationship between $\mathbb{Q}(a+bi)|\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(a)|\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(b)|\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ be algebraic with $\alpha=a+bi$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)|\mathbb{Q}$, with $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=n$.

My question is: is there any way to establish a relationship between the degree of the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(a)|\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(bi)|\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$?

I tried to use that both $\alpha$ and $\overline{\alpha}$ are roots of the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ and that $a=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\overline{\alpha})$ and $bi=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\overline{\alpha})$ with no success.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy to describe relation. The product of the two extension degrees gives an upper bound to $n$ for sure. But there are cases like $\alpha=\omega\root3\of 2$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, where the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $a$ are cubic, but that of $bi$ has degree six.

Comment: As you observed, $\Bbb{Q}(a,bi)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\overline{\alpha})$. The extension degree $[\Bbb{Q}(\overline{\alpha},\alpha):\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)]$ is thus the key. But AFAICT it can be pretty much anything from $1$ to $n-1$.